# Red Screen: Invalid Argument (onError): Error handler must accept one Ojbect or one Object and a Stacktrace as arguments.: Closure: () => Null

Tags: flutter, onerror

Getting this error and the relevant area of code is as follows. Not sure why this is happening or how to resolve:

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Widget cachedNetworkImage(String mediaUrl) {
  return CachedNetworkImage(
    imageUrl: mediaUrl,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    placeholder: (context, url) => Padding(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    ),
    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
  );
}
```

Comment: What version of cached_network_image are You using?

Comment: @josteve 

in the .packages file I see this: cached_network_image:file:///D:/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cached_network_image-2.0.0/lib/